# Can I use a Windows phone 7 as device with Windows phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm just confused, I just began Windows Phone programming and I was asking myself :

can I use a Windows phone 7 (HTC HD7) as device in Visual Studio 2013 and SDK for Windows Phone 8?

(sorry, maybe my question is stupid !)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon B is correct. If you want to develop Windows Phone apps and use your Windows Phone 7.x device, you need to go back to Visual Studio 2012 and install the Windows Phone 8 SDK, which allows development for both WP7.1 and 8.0.

To recap:

- Visual Studio 2013 + WP8 SDK (installer option): Build WP8.0 apps only
- Visual Studio 2012 + WP8 SDK (separate installer): Build WP7.1 & WP8.0 apps
- Visual Studio 2010 + WP7.1 SDK (separate installer): Build WP7.1 apps

Another important consideration is Windows. The version of Windows required is dictated by the WP SDK. The WP7.1 SDK requires Windows 7 & up. The WP8 SDK requires Windows 8 Pro & up.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i took visual studio 2013 at the beginning because i had thinked about the emulator  but i just got a device (which is usefull for geolocation etc). To conclude i need to go back to visual studio 2012 with the separate installer :)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Windows Phone 7 applications will run on a Windows Phone 8.  Window Phone 8 applications will not run on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 connects to the PC via Zune, Windows Phone 8 doesn't.